# Matching alpha values of a legend with the histogram in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I have a data.frame `pp` where the first few rows look like this,

```
  fill x
1 a    0.3048367
2 b    0.3318136
3 c    0.2081782
4 a    0.2969265
5 b    0.2637778
6 c    0.3509706
```

I want to create a plot like the following,

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(data = pp) + 
     geom_histogram(data=subset(pp, fill == 'a'),
         aes(x=x, y=..density.., fill=fill), alpha=0.3) + 
     geom_histogram(data=subset(pp, fill == 'b'),
         aes(x=x, y=..density.., fill=fill), alpha=0.3) + 
     geom_histogram(data=subset(pp, fill == 'c'),
         aes(x=x, y=..density.., fill=fill), alpha=0.3) +  
     scale_fill_manual(values = c("a" = "red", "b" = "green", c = "blue")) +  
     theme(legend.title=element_blank())
```

[image]

Now, the alpha values in the legend don't match the alpha values of the histogram. I try to add,

```
p + guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 0.3)))
```

but I get the exact same plot. How do I get the alpha values in the legend to match the plot?

Note: I must use `geom_histogram` three times because I want the histograms to be overlayed on top of each other. The specific fill to color mapping is also important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not have to use `geom_hisogram()` multiple times. The position of the bins is controlled with `position` argument, and `position='identity'` will give you what you want, while the default is `position='stack'`. `scale_fill_manual` already maps the colors properly, even with single `geom_histogram()` Please try the following code:

```
ggplot(pp, aes(x = x, y = ..density.., fill = fill)) +
  geom_histogram(alpha = .3, position = 'identity') +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('a' = 'red', 'b' = 'green', 'c' = 'blue'))
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you for showing me the "position" argument.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `position_identity` in the call to `geom_histogram` without having to call the function 3 times. This will also automatically update the alpha in the legend, as the alpha is only being set 1 time (instead of 3 times in each of the calls in your original code. Here is an example using some simulated data:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data_frame(
  a = rnorm(1000, 0, 1),
  b = rnorm(1000, 2, 1),
  c = rnorm(1000, -2, 0.5)
) %>%
  gather(key = "fill", value = "x")

df
#> # A tibble: 3,000 x 2
#>    fill       x
#>    <chr>  <dbl>
#>  1 a     -0.951
#>  2 a      0.321
#>  3 a      0.551
#>  4 a      0.166
#>  5 a     -1.55 
#>  6 a      1.27 
#>  7 a     -0.224
#>  8 a     -0.243
#>  9 a     -1.48 
#> 10 a     -0.888
#> # ... with 2,990 more rows

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, fill = fill)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), position = position_identity(), alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("a" = "red", "b" = "green", "c" = "blue")) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank())
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-10-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there.

```
pp=data.frame(fill=rep(c('a','b','c'),100),x=rnorm(300))

library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(data = pp) + 
     geom_histogram(data=subset(pp, fill == 'a'),
         aes(x=x, y=..density.., fill=fill), alpha=0.3) + 
     geom_histogram(data=subset(pp, fill == 'b'),
         aes(x=x, y=..density.., fill=fill), alpha=0.3) + 
     geom_histogram(data=subset(pp, fill == 'c'),
         aes(x=x, y=..density.., fill=fill), alpha=0.3) +  
     scale_fill_manual(values = c("a" = "red", "b" = "green", c = "blue"),aesthetics=c(alpha=.3)) +  
     theme(legend.title=element_blank())

p
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this code works for you.

`ggplot(pp,aes(x=x,stat(density))) + 
      geom_histogram(data=subset(pp,fill == 'a'),fill = "red", alpha = 0.3,binwidth = 0.05) +
      geom_histogram(data=subset(pp,fill== 'b'),fill = "green", alpha = 0.3,binwidth = 0.10) +
      geom_histogram(data=subset(pp,fill== 'c'),fill = "blue", alpha = 0.3,binwidth = 0.15)+
      theme(legend.title=element_blank())`